# Does this seem to be an error or something else? - Upgrading Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: upgrade

I did try the upgrade through Terminal using the below given command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Then it started downloading the required files. In between I could see the below lines also (mostly):

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                          

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US                                                            

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                                           

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                                     

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en_US                                                                     

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en_US                                                                       

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en_US                                                                   

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                             

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en_US                                                             

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en_US                                                               

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en_US                                                                 

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                           

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en_US                                                           

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en_US                                                             

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en_US                                                                  

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_US                                                            

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_US                                                            

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: Select best server from software and updates, and then update the repositories.

Comment: Is that the issue? It was 'server india' earlier. Then I changed to 'Main server'. Actually, how we could know which server is better?

Comment: Hey, the thing I have asked is different from the question that you have pointed out as duplicate. How it can be similar specifically? I'm asking about the error. Is this pointed out in duplicate question?

Comment: @RajeshCO Switch back over to your nearest mirror server. This might be a proxy issue with your telco not allowing the connection.

Comment: Network or Server issue. Internet is down or server is down.

Comment: It doesn't says what the error is, just "Err", copy the entire output instead.

Comment: Did you try doing the command again?